# Spring oauth2 custom token issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a requirement to generate a token manually in the code with a 3rd party has been verified. I'm running into an issue when I have to authenticate the token. I have created my own token store, which was working great when not generating the manual token. I also extended the The DefaultTokenService, but just added one method.

I have thrown in a few breakpoints and found that I'm hitting the ProviderManager class when I'm creating my own tokens manually. But when I'm not creating my own tokens, I'm hitting the UnanimousBased class. Not sure if that detail helps. Going to backtrace it more, but I'm open to any ideas.

Here is how I'm creating the token:

```
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> authorizationParameters = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
        authorizationParameters.put("scope", "read");
        authorizationParameters.put("username", "mobile_client");
        authorizationParameters.put("client_id", "mobile-client");
        authorizationParameters.put("grant", "password");

        DefaultAuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = new DefaultAuthorizationRequest(authorizationParameters);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_UNTRUSTED_CLIENT"));
        authorizationRequest.setAuthorities(authorities);

        HashSet<String> resourceIds = new HashSet<String>();
        resourceIds.add("mobile-client");
        authorizationRequest.setResourceIds(resourceIds);

        User userPrincipal = new User("mobile_client", "", true, true, true, true, authorities);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, null, authorities) ;

        OAuth2Authentication authenticationRequest = new OAuth2Authentication(authorizationRequest, authenticationToken);
        authenticationRequest.setAuthenticated(true);

        NoSQLTokenStore tokenStore = new NoSQLTokenStore();

        CustomTokenServices tokenServices = new CustomTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenServices.createAccessTokenForUser(authenticationRequest, user);
```

This is the exception being thrown:

```
Mobile App 17:02:21.169 [WARN] LoggerListener - Authentication event AuthenticationFailureProviderNotFoundEvent: mobile_client; details: remoteAddress=::1, , tokenValue=<TOKEN>; exception: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication
Mobile App 17:02:21.169 [DEBUG] ExceptionTranslationFilter - Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point <org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication>org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:196)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:202)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved my issue by adding `authorizationRequest.setApproved(true);`